# Copy first and last column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy, paste

I want to make a macro that copy's the first and last column to another sheet. I have made a recorded macro that selects column A and L in one sheet called Saldobalanse RHB input and copies them to the sheet: Saldobalanse RHB. The problem with this is that the numbers I need do not ALWAYS appear in the column L, sometimes it is in K or J. That's why I would like to copy the first and the last column - wherever the placement is. Could someone help me edit my recorded macro to fit this? Please and thank you so much in advance.

```
Sub Makro6()
    Makro6 Makro
    Range("A:A,L:L").Select
    Range("L1").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: [Avoid using select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) would help clean up this recorder code for one...

Comment: `usedrange.columns(1)` and `usedrange.columns(usedrange.columnscount)` ?

Comment: Thank you, I will try to study this link on how to avoid select. When you write usedrange.columns(usedrange.columnscount), do you mean that I should just write that or do I put something else in the parantese? I would like to use CTRL+SHIFT+R for this action to start. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

One of these examples should work for you:

### `Range.CurrentRegion`

```
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Target.Columns(1).Copy Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("A1")
Target.Columns(Target.Columns.Count).Copy Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("B1")
```

### `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`

```
Dim Target As Range
Set Target = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Target.Columns(1).Copy Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("A1")
Target.Columns(Target.Columns.Count).Copy Sheets("Saldobalanse RHB").Range("B1")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I Tried your code, but what it did was to put a filter on column A and B. Actually what I want to do is select the first column and last columns and copy them to A1 in another Sheet. I tried watching the video someone sent to avoid select. This was a lot of information for me, I realize I will have to study to understand truly how to edit a recorded macro.

Comment: @EllenSophie This code does not add a filter.  Download this workbook and try it out:   [Copy First and Last Columns](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T0ckTb2RZPBEWKtmfAzk8YVZl9u-2bjm/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=114888086960932662321&rtpof=true&sd=true).  The only difference in the download is that I do not use the ActiveSheet.  Let me know how it works.  You may want to read: [Range.Copy method (Excel)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144104);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Comment: @EllenSophie Note:  the code will overwrite the data on **Saldobalanse RHB**.